# Onesignal-php to android

Tags: php, android, onesignal

I have this php script:

```html
<?php
function sendMessage(){
$content = array(
  "en" => 'text message test'
  );

$fields = array(
  'app_id' => "XXXXXX",
  'included_segments' => array('All'),
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
  'headings' => array("en" => "Test message!!"),
"isAndroid"=>true,
//  'android_group'  => 'Tanks',
 // 'android_group_message' => array("en" => "message"),
  'contents' => $content
);

$fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                       'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
?>
```

But is doesn't end notifactions to android users. Is there a example to send pushnotifications from php over OneSignal to android devies?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i did not add my one sognal authentication code ;)